# Using multiple tables on FROM with procedure?

Tags: sql

This is how my question looks from the SQL procedure, how can I use multiple tables in the FROM ?

```
ELSE IF @Case = 6 BEGIN
                        SELECT
                        Country,
                        PostalCode,
                        WorkshopId,
                        Comment,
                        Lat,
                        Lng,
                        Box,
                        30km,
                        Installation,
                        WorkShopId_HomeService,
                        WorkSHopId_Installation
                        FROM dbo.tbl_PostalCode AS PC WITH (NOLOCK)

                        WHERE (Country = @Country)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL SELECT from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416003/sql-select-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request you to please study about `Joins` for getting data from more than 1 table.

**[Study SQL JOIN Explanation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)**

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Use JOINs . Have a loo at [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)