# Select with two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables `hits` and `posts`. In `hits`table I have `id_post,hits` and the `posts`table I have `id,title`

I need build the report with all posts with related hits and order by hits. Can anyone  help me with select?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1416023/50447

Comment: yes this should be marked as duplicate as mentioned by @Rowland Shaw

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT   posts.id as id, posts.title as title, hits.hits as hitsdate
FROM     posts INNER JOIN hits ON hits.id_post = posts.id
ORDER BY hits.hits
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   posts.id, posts.title, hits.hits
FROM     posts LEFT JOIN hits ON hits.id_post = posts.id
ORDER BY hits.hits
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `title`;");
while($qresult=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
    $post_id=$qresult['id'];
    $post_title=$qresult['title'];
    $hitsretreiver=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `hits` WHERE `id_post`='$post_id';")
    while($hitsretreiverresult=mysql_fetch_array($hitsretreiver)
    {
         $relatd_hit=$hitsretreiverresult['hits'];
         echo $post_title;
         echo $relatd_hit;
    }
 }
```

in this code you get every record in the table post and you get the record from table hits which has the same id