# How to get country,state,city name in the most optimized way from different tables

Tags: php, database, mysqli, pdo

I have a employee table,city country and state table.
My employee table stores id of country state and city.
I want country_name, state_name, city_name using mysqli query in optimized form.

**employee table**

```
emp_id  name  email         country  state   city
------- ----   -----         -------  ------  -----
    1    abc  a@gmail.com     1      1       1
```

**country table**

```
country_id    country_name
-----------   -------------
1                India
```

**state table**

```
state_id  country_id  state_name
--------  ----------  -----------
1            1          Gujarat
```

**city table**

```
city_id   state_id  city_name
-------    -------   --------
1            1       Ahmedabad
```

**Function used to fetch the data**

```
  function select_employee(){
      $sth =  $this->con->prepare("SELECT  * from employees");
      $sth->execute();
      $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      return $result;
  }
```

**Function to display state,city,country**

```
  function select_places(){
          $sth =  $this->con->prepare("SELECT country.country_name,state.state_name,city.city_name
                                                                            FROM employees
                                                                            LEFT JOIN country ON employees.country = country.country_id
                                                                            LEFT JOIN state ON employees.state = state.state_id
                                                                            LEFT JOIN city ON employees.city = city.city_id");
          $sth->execute();
          $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          return $result;
      }
```

**printing data**

```
<?php
   foreach ($result as $values){
                ?>
        </tr>
        <td><?php echo $values['country']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $values['state']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $values['city']; ?></td>
     }
```

In the print data section i need data India,Gujarat,Ahmedabad.
Not their ids.

**output**

```
country_name  state_name  city_name
------------  --------   ----------
1                1           1
```

**what i need**

```
 emp_id   name    email       country_name   state_name    city_name
   -----   ----   -------      ------------   --------     ----------
    1      abc    ab@gm.com      India         Gujarat      Ahmedabad
```

how can i prepare the query or join for that? that using id from employee i get name from country,state,city table

Comment: What is wrong with using JOIN?

Comment: it gives id of city state country, i need their names

Comment: Because you are printing the wrong values. The value "state" will always be the id. You should use "<?php echo $values['xxx_name']; ?> instead.

Comment: editted pls check now

Comment: You need `country_name`, `state_name`, and `city_name` yet are printing something completely different (`$values['country']; [...])`?

Comment: you need to join

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL SELECT from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416003/sql-select-from-multiple-tables)

Comment: how can i prepare the query or join for that? that using id from employee i get name from country,state,city table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Function**

```php
 function select_employee(){
      $select = "SELECT * from employees";
      $select .= " join country on employees.country_id = country.country_id";
      $select .= " join state on employees.state_id = state.state_id";
      $select .= " join city on employees.city_id = city.city_id";
      $sth =  $this->con->prepare($select);
      $sth->execute();
      $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      return $result;
  }
```

**Printing**

```php
<?php foreach ($result as $values): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $values['country_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $values['state_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $values['city_name']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: question edited pls help.. i need also the datas from emp table, so do i have to use second function and make a select * query ?

Answer (score 1):

Change `$sth =  $this->con->prepare("SELECT * from employees");` to

```
$sth =  $this->con->prepare("      
SELECT employees.* country_table.country_name, state_table.state_name, city_table.city_name FROM 
   (((employees INNER JOIN country_table ON employees.country_id = country_table.country_id)
   INNER JOIN state_table ON employees.state_id = state_table.state_id)
   INNER JOIN city_table ON employees.city_id = city_table.city_id)");
```

Comment: you are joining the state/country/city id's with employee id. This won't work for sure.. ;)

Comment: question edited pls help.. i need also the datas from emp table, so do i have to use second function and make a select * query ?

Comment: @DhruvThakkar I edited my answer now you also get everything from the emplpyee table